# Saving Map Data using SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

My app tracks the movement of user. Now wanna save that to sqlite and so later I can trace the road travelled from source to destination

Does anyone know how to save the Map data to sqlite using Xcode? My map tracks the movement of the user from Source to destination and now struck here in saving it to DB. So user can save the direction for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CLLocationManager` you can get the starting point and finishing point coordinates, meanwhile you could get intermediate points too, so you can try saving these coordinates and using them again to draw the same route.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. And many a thanks for your time to reply me.